# Click challenge with simple acordition menu

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make some acordion menu, but I face a small porblem. The point is that everything works fine when I click the first panel the slide expands, when I click the second it works,idem. But, when I start again and click the first one, surprise, nothing happens, I click again and only then the slide expands :D

[here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Code_me/DDSu2/2/)!

```
$('#one').toggle(function(){
$('.content').animate({width:'42%'});
$('.content1').animate({width:'0%'});    
}, function(){ 
$('.content').animate({width:'0%'});
});


$('#two').toggle(function(){
$('.content1').animate({width:'42%'});
$('.content').animate({width:'0%'});    
}, function(){ 
$('.content1').animate({width:'0%'});
});
```

It's weird and i want them to expand from the first click.Can someone help me ?

Comment: Avoid using toggle is deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few flaws in your approach. First off, if you want this to be scalable, re-use classes. Second, you want your jQuery to target a class not unique elements, since you want it to work in any context.
I took the liberty of adjusting your html:

```
<ul id="vertical">
    <li id="one" class="panel"></li>
    <li class="content"></li>
    <li id="two" class="panel"></li>
    <li class="content"></li>
    <li id="three" class="panel"></li>
    <li class="content"></li>
</ul>
```

The JavaScript approach can then also be a lot more elegant. You don't need to check for every element, since you know which one you have to expand.

```
$('.panel').click(function(){

    //hide everything
    $(".content").stop().animate({"width": 0}, 500);

    //animate the target element to the desired width
    //because animations are asynchronous, this line will execute immediately after the first,
    //the stop() will ensure this element will immediately stop whatever animation it was doing,
    //and then animate to 42%
    $(this).next().stop().animate({"width": "42%"}, 500);       
});
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/DDSu2/5/)

Comment: I understand your point of view ,but i still have to toggle all this. i've made another example with toggle and i still have to click twice once i start again from the first, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Code_me/DDSu2/7/